# iOS Using Vision in Real Time with ARKit inference performance degradation

Tags: ios, deep-learning, computer-vision, arkit, coreml

This problem can be easily illustrated from apple sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit). I observed that the amount of time for the inception v3 network to make an inference/prediction drift higher and higher over time. Starting with around 400ms to 800-900ms. I have a comparably deep net which I have observed over 1 sec to make a prediction. The app becomes pretty unusable (real time and with AR).

For quick and dirty profiling, i just did a tic/toc:

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: currentBuffer!, orientation: orientation)
    visionQueue.async {
        do {
            // Release the pixel buffer when done, allowing the next buffer to be processed.
            defer { self.currentBuffer = nil }
            self.tik = Date()
            try requestHandler.perform([self.classificationRequest])
            let tok = Date()
            let executionTime = tok.timeIntervalSince(self.tik)
            print("Total Execution time: \(executionTime*1000) ms")
        } catch {
            print("Error: Vision request failed with error \"\(error)\"")
        }
```

This makes for a nice demo for 1 or 2 min but it seemed to suffer some visible frame drop. Anyone have seen this, and any pointers on how to debug? i am new to this, i may need to dig a bit into one of the Instrument. But it will be great if someone out there with deep experiencing in this sort of debugging. It will also make a good discussion if this is indeed some bug on Apple's side.

**Additional insight**: I also also found out a good reason the sample code has decided to run the inception only on CPU, sparing the GPU to do AR and SceneKit graphics. In one of my runs, I turned this off such that the net can use GPU. This seems to create an intense competition between AR and Vision when both want GPU power. I subsequently also observed that moving the phone around can have a big hit on FPS and the inference time due to AR trying to track phone (plus i also added plane detection, which all stressed the whole phone out heating it up).

Comment: Could be a temperature induced throttling of the CPU...

Comment: Further note: i tried both request.usesCPUOnly = true and false. Setting this to false (the default) let GPU does the inference, and it is indeed faster. But it suffers the same drift to high latency after a few min of continuous run.

Comment: Try in the fridge. If CPU or GPU is too hot, iOS will reduce clock speed.

Comment: If this is true, am I at the breeding edge?? I stripped away the post-processing code and laying bare just the CNN inference, and I still observed this bad behavior. I will try and do some experiments. Otherwise, the only other option is to use a lighter network and smaller image input.

Comment: Inception v3 is a pretty heavy model, so it's no surprise that the device gets hot and the GPU slows down. I've seen this with all models I've tried, even small ones. Instead of running the model as often as you can, try running it as little as possible (e.g. when the user isn't waving the device around too much).

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thanks for your advice. Yes, I convinced myself the drift is due to this. If i suspend it and restart, it will quickly regain its initial performance. Is there any good strategy and sample code on how to proactively throttle model inference? I am beginning to think of using a super light model (but surly very inaccurate) to run pretty frequently and let it decide if the heavier accurate one should be activated.

Comment: It depends on what your use case is. There is a WWDC 2018 session video, Vision with CoreML, that shows how to use VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest to determine if the camera is moving too much. That's useful for when people are walking around and want to classify things they point their camera at. Only do the classification once the camera isn't moving too much anymore. But I don't know what your use case is, so perhaps this isn't a good solution for you.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans. Thanks. I will definitely check out the code sample and demo.

Answer (score 0):

@MatthijsHollemans. I reviewed the WWDC 2018 session video "Vision with CoreML". This seems reasonably simple to do given they have a nice API and sample code, although it may not be optimal but good simple heuristics. I will try implement it.

Additionally, it may make sense:

1) detect if the image had gone totally dark (user put the phone down face up)

2) If cnn inference detect no obj, then it should also stop making new inference. Since if new obj moves into the scene, it will trigger image delta to re-awaken it. This may work if you net has more false positives than false negative. i.e. it is very eager to make predictions than not.